# how to write LDAP client using java

Tags: java, openldap

My requirement is I have to connect LDAP Server by using java.My admin gave

```
IP :             
HOST :           
LDAP PORT :      
LDAP USER NAME : 
PasSWORD :
```

these details to connect LDAP.Now i want to delvelope ldap client by using JAVA.

Can any one Suggest how to proceed?I do not have any idea to proceed.

Comment: What you want? Just an app to connect and fetch some information? Try Spring LDAP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using spring it will be very easy.Define a bean in xml or java which ever way you config.For XML

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
    <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userdn}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>
```

Load those property tags using Property Place Holder.
Use `LdapTemplate` in your required class

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
```

Sample Query using `LdapTemplate`

```
    public boolean isUserExistsInLdap(String emailId, String password) {
        boolean auth = false;
            try {
                auth = ldapTemplate.authenticate("","mail="
                        + emailId, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
          return auth;
    }
```

Comment: i am not found any authenticate method in ldapTemplate

Comment: r u using this spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar as dependency

Comment: yes i am using spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: authenticate method is there I am using in my project.ru using ldapTemplate  or I think you may have errors in your project build.check once if u have a problem still. mail to  sarath@smargav.com with snapshots I can check.

Comment: authenticate  is avaiable.i used spring-ldap.jar file.

Comment: String emailId = "lara@gmail.com";String password = "welcome";
LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate();
ldapTemplate.authenticate("", "mail=" + emailId,password);.......lara details is avaiable in my ldapserver.now i am checking weather lara is avaialble or not.

Comment: but i am getting exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, including but not limited to:

- JNDI
- The UnboundID API
- the Spring API
- the Netscape API (now at Mozilla.org)
- the Novell API
- ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java EE use JNDI to access LDAP:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html

Or if you use Spring try Spring LDAP:
http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/